# Webフレームワーク内でasyncioを使用した並列処理を試みると`this event loop is already running`が発生する

Tags: python, python3

#### 処理の内容

Python 3.6.8 で asyncio と Requests で複数の HTTP リクエストを並列で送信しています。それぞれの完了を待ち合わせ、レスポンスの本文を結合する必要があります。

```py
import  asyncio, requests

# requestsを使用しHTTPリクエストを行うだけのコルーチン
async def coroutine(url):
    try:
        res = requests.get(url=url)
        return res.json()
    except:
        return {}

# 複数のリクエストを並列で送信
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
    coroutine("https://public.bitbank.cc/btc_jpy/ticker"),
    coroutine("https://www.btcbox.co.jp/api/v1/ticker/"),
    coroutine("https://coincheck.com/api/ticker")
))

print(len(results)) # 3
```

上記のコードは上手く動きます。

しかし、これを Responder や AIOHTTP といった HTTP サーバーに持ち込むとイベントループの使用について問題が発生します。

#### Responderに取り込んだ場合

わたしは REST API の実装に取り組んでおり、複数の外部サーバからリソースを並列な方法で取得し、その全ての結果を結合して返す API を提供しようと Responder を使用し次のようなコードを書きました:

```py
# api.py

import asyncio, responder, requests

async def coroutine(url):
    try:
        res = requests.get(url=url)
        return res.json()
    except:
        return {}

api = responder.API()

@api.route("/tickers")
class tickers:
    async def on_get(self, req, resp):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
            coroutine("https://public.bitbank.cc/btc_jpy/ticker"),
            coroutine("https://www.btcbox.co.jp/api/v1/ticker/"),
            coroutine("https://coincheck.com/api/ticker")
        ))
        body = {"results": results}
        resp.media = body

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api.run()
```

これを `python api.py` で実行し、稼働したローカルサーバ `http://localhost:5042/tickers` にアクセスすると次のようなエラーが発生します。

```
...

RuntimeError: this event loop is already running.
```

#### AIOHTTPの場合

AIOHTTP を使用しても同じように `this event loop is already running.` が出力されます。

```py
# app.py

import asyncio, requests
from aiohttp import web

async def coroutine(url):
    try:
        res = requests.get(url=url)
        return res.json()
    except:
        return {}

routes = web.RouteTableDef()

@routes.get("/tickers")
async def tickers(request):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
        coroutine("https://public.bitbank.cc/btc_jpy/ticker"),
        coroutine("https://www.btcbox.co.jp/api/v1/ticker/"),
        coroutine("https://coincheck.com/api/ticker")
    ))
    body = { "results": results }
    return web.json_response(body)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes(routes)
    web.run_app(app)
```

---

Responder や AIOHTTP のようなフレームワークを使用する場合、どのようにすれば内部の処理において並列処理（主に外部サーバへ HTTP リクエストを送信するため）を行えるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tickers`そのものがイベントループから実行されるコルーチンです。
ですからその中でイベントループを起こさず、`await`で別のコルーチンに移譲します。

```py
results = await asyncio.gather(
    coroutine("https://public.bitbank.cc/btc_jpy/ticker"),
    coroutine("https://www.btcbox.co.jp/api/v1/ticker/"),
    coroutine("https://coincheck.com/api/ticker")
))
```

Comment: 特に「コルーチンの中でイベントループを起こさず」という部分がとても参考になりました。本番コードでもコルーチンをまとめてループを使って実行する関数をコルーチンとして作成していたりと正しくない入れ子構成にしていました